# Can I edit fields in a database using a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I have a database of links that all point to a specific site, but different pages on that site. Well the site's domain changed and I need to update my database to reflect that change. I only need to change the domain name, the rest of the link works fine.

My question is, can I use a rails migration to do this? To edit all fields in a column and update them? What would this look like?

I know there are other ways to approach it, but I want to explore the options I would have with a rails migration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you have two options. 1) You can write ActiveRecord code in migrations just like you would in a model, e.g.:

```
class ChangeDomainName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    YourModel.update_all "url = REPLACE(url, 'www.old-domain-name.com', 'www.new-domain-name.com')"
  end

  def self.down
    # ...
  end
end
```

One thing to remember in this scenario is that if you're changing e.g. column names or types in the same migration before `update_all` you need to do `YourModel.reset_column_information` after altering the table and before calling ActiveRecord methods on it.

2) You can use raw SQL with the "execute" method:

```
def self.up
  execute "UPDATE your_models SET url = REPLACE(url, 'www.old-domain-name.com', 'www.new-domain-name.com)"
end
```

Personally I prefer the first method.

Comment: My links have ID's in them to different elements in the app that I would like to maintain. Is there a way I can only update the domain name and keep the rest of the link intact?

Comment: My code--specifically MySQL's `REPLACE()` function--does exactly that, jfedick. Take a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace